Longtable with multirow linewrapping
I wanted to build a complex table using longtable and multirow. For some reason however, the text in my multirow does not want to wrap and just starts going into another cell next to it. This is specifically an issue in the Stakeholders row.
The code below is just a fragment of my document, but should contain everything used in the creation of the table
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcommand{\autism}{autistic people}
\newcommand{\Autism}{Autistic people}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{ |M{0.1\linewidth}|M{0.39\linewidth}|M{0.39\linewidth}| }
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Issue}} & \textbf{What problem do you want to tackle with your idea?} & \textbf{Who is the target audience?} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & Lessen the boundary and difficulty to meet other \autism{}, and help \autism{} build a routine or change an existing routine. & \Autism{}. \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{8}{*}{\textbf{Idea}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Describe your idea}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{We want to make an application which gives the possibility to build a routine and  find other people/groups based on their special interest. We would also like to encourage them into being more active by making the app also like a game. In this game we would like to add something like a tycoon / doulingo type game. Another feature we would add is something to help with their planning to make it easier for them to change their routine and implement a physical acitivity in it.} \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Impact}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{\textbf{What impact do you intend to have with your idea? What are the benefits?}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{We want them to have a better and healthier routine.
    We would like to make it easier for people with autism to meet eachother and also try to make their life more active by sporting in group or alone.} \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Pitfalls}} & \textbf{What pitfalls does your idea have?} & \textbf{What can be a potential solution for these pitfalls?} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & We need a userbase for our idea to work & We already have people who want to be notified of our project if we achieve something, so they could be a potential starting userbase \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{8}{*}{\textbf{Stakeholders}} & \textbf{Which stakeholders are necessary to realize your idea?} & \textbf{What role do these stakeholders fulfill?} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & The experts & The experts give us valuable information and help us to connect with \autism{} \\
    & \Autism{} & \Autism{} give us feedback and if they don't like it, it won't work \\
    \hline
    \caption{Our idea of the product}
    \label{tab:idea_canvas}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}



Have a look at the tabularray package. It makes it easy to merge cells and has environments for multi-page tables.

What happens if you change Stakeholders to Stake\-holders?

@Mico Nothing happens

Instead of  \multirow{...}{*}{...˙} try to use \multirow{...}{=*}{...˙}  and consider @Mico comment. Also I would consider first comment.

@Zarko Thanks! Using = instead of *, combined with the - seems to have worked!

ups, in my comment should be \multirow{...}{=}{...} ....

@Zarko Could you please add your comment as an answer with code example, so that others can see the question is answered?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@dsacre, done. With two additional better designed tables examples.

It is not clear, why you need longtable and if all multirow cells except last span two rows.
Anyway, let me firs extend my comment to an answer. Package multirow also offer option =. It prescribe multirow cell width equal to column width (in which is multirow cell). Using this, your MWE is:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=3cm, vmargin=2cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcommand{\autism}{autistic people}
\newcommand{\Autism}{Autistic people}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{ |M{0.1\linewidth}|M{0.39\linewidth}|M{0.39\linewidth}| }
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{=}{\textbf{Issue}} & \textbf{What problem do you want to tackle with your idea?} & \textbf{Who is the target audience?} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & Lessen the boundary and difficulty to meet other \autism{}, and help \autism{} build a routine or change an existing routine. & \Autism{}. \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{8}{=}{\textbf{Idea}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{\textbf{Describe your idea}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{We want to make an application which gives the possibility to build a routine and  find other people/groups based on their special interest. We would also like to encourage them into being more active by making the app also like a game. In this game we would like to add something like a tycoon / doulingo type game. Another feature we would add is something to help with their planning to make it easier for them to change their routine and implement a physical acitivity in it.} \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Impact}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{\textbf{What impact do you intend to have with your idea? What are the benefits?}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{M{0.8\linewidth}|}{We want them to have a better and healthier routine.
    We would like to make it easier for people with autism to meet eachother and also try to make their life more active by sporting in group or alone.} \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{5}{=}{\textbf{Pitfalls}} & \textbf{What pitfalls does your idea have?} & \textbf{What can be a potential solution for these pitfalls?} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & We need a userbase for our idea to work & We already have people who want to be notified of our project if we achieve something, so they could be a potential starting userbase \\
    \hhline{===}
    \multirow{8}{=}{\textbf{Stakeholders}} & \textbf{Which stakeholders are necessary to realize your idea?} & \textbf{What role do these stakeholders fulfill?} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & The experts & The experts give us valuable information and help us to connect with \autism{} \\
    & \Autism{} & \Autism{} give us feedback and if they don't like it, it won't work \\
    \hline
    \caption{Our idea of the product}
    \label{tab:idea_canvas}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

and result is:

However, instead longtable I would rather use longtblr of tabularray package (in the case that your table is really long) or in the case that you like to reproduce just showed table
Assuming, that you like to reproduce only showed table, the MWE can be:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=3cm, vmargin=2cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\newcommand{\autism}{autistic people}
\newcommand{\Autism}{Autistic people}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[l, wd=0.1\linewidth]
                            X[j] X[j] @{}},
             cell{odd[1-X]}{1} = {r=2}{},
             row{odd[1-X]}     = {m, font=\small\bfseries},
             rowsep  = 3pt,
             hspan   = minimal,
              }
    \toprule
Issue   &   What problem do you want to tackle with your idea?
            &   Who is the target audience?         
                        \\
        &   Lessen the boundary and difficulty to meet other \autism, and help \autism build a routine or change an existing routine.
            & \Autism.  \\
    \midrule
Idea    &   \SetCell[c=2]{}   Describe your idea
            &           \\
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{}   We want to make an application which gives the possibility to build a routine and  find other people/groups based on their special interest. We would also like to encourage them into being more active by making the app also like a game. In this game we would like to add something like a tycoon / doulingo type game. Another feature we would add is something to help with their planning to make it easier for them to change their routine and implement a physical activity in it.
            &           \\
    \midrule
Impact  &   \SetCell[c=2]{}   What impact do you intend to have with your idea? What are the benefits?
            &           \\ 
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{}    We want them to have a better and healthier routine. We would like to make it easier for people with autism to meet each other and also try to make their life more active by sporting in group or alone.
            &           \\
    \midrule
Pitfall &   What pitfalls does your idea have?
            &   What can be a potential solution for these pitfalls?
                        \\
        &   We need a userbase for our idea to work 
            &   We already have people who want to be notified of our project if we achieve something, so they could be a potential starting user base \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=3]{}    Stake\-holders
        &   Which stakeholders are necessary to realize your idea?
            &   \SetCell{m,font=\small\bfseries}  What role do these stakeholders fulfill?
                        \\
        &   The experts 
            &   The experts give us valuable information and help us to connect with \autism.
                        \\
        &   \Autism 
            &   \Autism give us feedback and if they don't like it, it won't work \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Our idea of the product}
\label{tab:idea_canvas}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


In case, that you table is really long, and that multirow cells spans different number of rows than above MWE become a bit more complex:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=3cm, vmargin=2cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\BFc{\SetCell{m,font=\small\bfseries}}
\NewTableCommand\BFcc{\SetCell[c=2]{m,font=\small\bfseries}}

\newcommand{\autism}{autistic people}
\newcommand{\Autism}{Autistic people}

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Our idea of the product},
  label = {tab:idea_canvas},
                    ]{colspec = {@{} Q[l, wd=0.1\linewidth, font=\small\bfseries]
                                    X[j] X[j] @{}},
                     rowsep  = 3pt,
                     hspan   = minimal,
                      }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{}   Issue   
        &   \BFc    What problem do you want to tackle with your idea?
            &   \BFc    Who is the target audience?         
                        \\
        &   Lessen the boundary and difficulty to meet other \autism, and help \autism build a routine or change an existing routine.
            & \Autism.  \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=2]{}   Idea    
        &   \BFcc    Describe your idea
            &           \\
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{}   We want to make an application which gives the possibility to build a routine and  find other people/groups based on their special interest. We would also like to encourage them into being more active by making the app also like a game. In this game we would like to add something like a tycoon / doulingo type game. Another feature we would add is something to help with their planning to make it easier for them to change their routine and implement a physical activity in it.
            &           \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=2]{}   Impact  
        &   \BFcc   What impact do you intend to have with your idea? What are the benefits?
            &           \\ 
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{}    We want them to have a better and healthier routine. We would like to make it easier for people with autism to meet each other and also try to make their life more active by sporting in group or alone.
            &           \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=2]{}   Pitfall 
        &   \BFc   What pitfalls does your idea have?
            &   \BFc   What can be a potential solution for these pitfalls?
                        \\
        &   We need a userbase for our idea to work 
            &   We already have people who want to be notified of our project if we achieve something, so they could be a potential starting user base \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=3]{}    Stake\-holders
        &   \BFc   Which stakeholders are necessary to realize your idea?
            &   \BFc What role do these stakeholders fulfill?
                        \\
        &   The experts 
            &   The experts give us valuable information and help us to connect with \autism.
                        \\
        &   \Autism 
            &   \Autism give us feedback and if they don't like it, it won't work \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}


Note: At long table is sensible to have caption at top of table.
